# Azure App Service Multi Containers and Storage?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=basic%2Cportal&pivots=container-linux) Microsoft documentation says: Azure Storage isn't supported with Docker Compose scenarios

But [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app) tutorial shows in the yaml a `db_data` being mounted which to me looks like Azure storage being used with multi container.

Does anyone know if it should work with multi container apps?

Answer (score 1):

These two docs are talking about different things.

[Mount Azure Storage as a local share in App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=basic%2Cportal&pivots=container-linux) is referring to BYOD, where you're attaching your own storage account to your app service and mapping a path on in your multi-container app for persistence. You enable this in the Mount Storage pane under the Configuration blade. This, as far as I know, is not supported.

[Tutorial: Create a multi-container (preview) app in Web App for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app) on the other hand, is referring to persistent storage on the underlying storage used by your app service. This storage is shared by the app service instances (ask scale in and out) and is removed if your app is ever deleted. In short, it's using `/home/site/wwwroot` to persist between restarts. You enable this by adding `WEBSITES_ENABLED_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` in the App Settings pane under the Configuration blade.